# ER_PARSE_ERROR node.js and mysql issue (INSERT INTO)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, syntax-error

I want to do a simple insert with Node.js while I am using socket.io with node.js and MySQL. Don't know why, but I am geting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''markos'' at line 1

My code:
When I try this, I get the above error.

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){
console.log("a user is connected " + socket.id );


    socket.on("question", function (question){

        let sql = "INSERT INTO nodeJs (name) VALUES ?";

        con.query(sql, question, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 record inserted");
        });


    });

  });
});
```

if I try this simple code, everything works fine:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){
console.log("a user is connected " + socket.id );


    socket.on("question", function (question){

        let sql = "INSERT INTO nodeJs (name) VALUES ('John')";

        con.query(sql, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 record inserted");
        });

    });

 });
});
```

The question parameter always has a string.

Comment: Try this:  let sql = "INSERT INTO nodeJs (name) VALUES (' + question + ')";. Note the simple quotes  ' '

Comment: In order to avoid sql injections i wouldn't recommend this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses around the values:

```js
let sql = "INSERT INTO nodeJs (name) VALUES (?)";
// Here ------------------------------------^-^
```

Comment: i just can't believe that i was missing this ! I still learning node.js and i was studying throw w3School https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp . They are not putting parenthesis like you..
Anyway thank you very much for your time

Comment: @Markos yes there are parenthesis because mysql needs then

Comment: @Markos you skip parenthesis with this syntax only: `INSERT INTO nodeJs SET name= ?` where you also don't use single quotes around the quesiton mark